# Cannot send ERC20 tokens because user has no ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, web3j, exchanges, address.transfer

I have 1 wallet server but have many account address for each user, so when user want to transfer erc-20 token say OMG to another address(user) in the same wallet server, the system said can not because no fee(user don't have ETH.

Has someone had this problem or have any idea on how to manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All transactions on Ethereum, including the transfer of ERC20 tokens, require some amount of Gas to be paid. A transaction with a Gas Price of 0 ETH will likely not get mined, and be rejected by the network.

You can use a service like [ETH Gas Station](https://ethgasstation.info/) to calculate the Gas Price you should be using for your transaction.

Your best solution is to transfer a little bit of ETH to the accounts holding your tokens so that you may complete the transaction. Remember to take into account that it also costs a fee to transfer your ETH from one address to another.